# How to get same format of order data like we get from Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales-order

I have a module which generates the Xml file when a order is placed on my store. In that module I am using the observer to get order data and for creating the XML file. XML contains all the the data of that Order.

Now, I want to create that XML by using a custom PHP script which is placed in root of the website. By using that Custom script I am trying to fetch the orders and creating the XML for them.

So the problem is when I create XML from Observer data then It contains different fields in XML and When I create XML from That PHP script, It contains different XML fields.

For custom Script I am using below method to fetch order data:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

And for Observer I am using below method to fetch order data:

```
$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

But Both collections are returning different format of Order data. Can anyone please help me out to get same data format?

Thanks

Comment: you can get order id from observer and then use $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*') to get data of particular order

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

This is because, `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')` will give you a resource collection instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` and whereas `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()` will most probably return a model instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.

If you want to make your observer code compatible with first one, then the following workaround may work.

```
  $collection = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection();
  $order      = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
  $collection->addItem($order);
```

Now your `$collection` holds a collection instance which has your `$order` as an item in it. Now you can use `$collection` as you like.

Though I didn't understand why you need this, I really hope you get the idea.

### EDIT - 1

Reverse transformation is not possible since it is not clear in what context you are trying to load that resource collection. Also the collection that you have given is a broader one (It holds all sales orders).

So you need to be more specific in your question. Otherwise this question is no longer beneficial either to you and for the community

### EDIT - 2

So basically you have a PHP Script file in your root directory and you need the last order information in that file. For that, you can use this code :

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->setOrder('increment_id','DESC')
     ->setPageSize(1)
     ->setCurPage(1);
$order = $orders->getFirstItem();
```

Here `$order` holds the last placed order (very recent order).

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I think you suggesting the reverse solution. I want to make the $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*'); compatible to Obeserver data. So the data which observer get and the data which I get in Custom file both will be the same.

Comment: @Dheeraj see my edit.

Comment: Please check my edited question.

Comment: @Dheeraj you need to create xml file per order ? or you want to generate an xml file for all orders ?

Comment: XML file will be per order.

Comment: @Dheeraj see my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48466/discussion-between-dheeraj-and-rajeev-k-tomy).